# Access value generated by trigger after save changes

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

```
        var school = new Models.School();

        SchoolCommandToSchool.Map(school, model);

        _schoolRepository.Add(school);

        _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();

        school.Code // is null
```

After insert i generate a school Code inside a trigger and store in the Code column. But after save changes i get a null.

Entity didn't know to fetch the data from column if i wrote that data inside an insert trigger?

Can someone explain what's happening?

Comment: I believe that EF does not recognize scripts inside an insert trigger. What are you doing in your trigger? maybe we can use other approach...

Comment: I generate that code based on some other data (from the database) and after that check if the generated code already exists (in the db). It's quite a lot of work to modify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use changeTracker, to track changes in your object. Like this:

Inside your DbContext class (not tested code):

```
public override int SaveChanges() {
    //detect the changes
    this.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    //get the schools object, if it exists
    //you also can check if the object is being insert or updated
    // i => i.State == EntityState.Modified or EntityState.Added
    var entries = this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(i => i.Entity.GetType() == typeof(School);

    if (entries.Any())
    {
        foreach (var entry in entries) {
            //do the trigger job in entry object;
        }
    }


    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Everytime you change a School you run an additional code.